# Enviar el context desde un fragment

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-context

espero se encuentren bien, soy novato en la programacion android, quiero realizar un slider de imagenes como aparecen en muchas apps y creé un SliderAdapter y este necesita que le envien un context, este slider estaría en un fragment , el problema es que no se como obtener el context del fragment para enviarlo al adapter, espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias

```
class Inicio : Fragment() { 
var context:Context //Esto no funciona
var images:Array<Int> = arrayOf(R.drawable.superman, R.drawable.batman, R.drawable.linternaverde)
var adapter:PagerAdapter = SliderAdapter()
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false)
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando `Kotlin` para obtener el contexto desde un `Fragment` puedes usar:

```
val appContext = context!!.applicationContext
```

para obtenerlo puedes realizarlo dentro de `onCreateView()` :

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    //Obtiene contexto.
    val appContext = context!!.applicationContext

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false)
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega el método `onAttach()` que recibe como parámetro el contexto y en ese método inicializa la propiedad `contexto` de la clase Inicio

```
 class Inicio : Fragment() { 
       lateinit var contexto:Context //Esto no funciona
       var images:Array<Int> = arrayOf(R.drawable.superman, R.drawable.batman, R.drawable.linternaverde)
       var adapter:PagerAdapter = SliderAdapter()

       override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
         super.onAttach(context)
         this.contexto = context
        }

       override fun onCreateView(
         inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
         savedInstanceState: Bundle?
         ): View? {
             // Inflate the layout for this fragment
             return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false)
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar **requireContext()** para inicializar el contexto en el *Fragment*.

Comment: Deberias mejorar la respuesta.